# Unable to parse response using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I have a js file that posts a `JSON` object using `$.ajax`, and then my php script takes that JSON object and does stuff to it, however, i can't get a json response back from the php script (the success callback function never runs).

register_script.js:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/login/webservices/register2.php",
    data: {
        reg_username: username,
        email: email,
        reg_password: password,
        confirm_password: confirm_pass
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hello?");
        //alert(data.status);           

    }
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Post error: " + errorThrown);
});
```

register2.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['reg_username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['reg_password'], $_POST['confirm_password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['reg_username']; //$_POST['from html']
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = hash('md5', ($_POST['reg_password']));
    $confirm_password2 = hash('md5', ($_POST['confirm_password']));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')";

    if ($password == $confirm_password2) {
        $response = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($response) {
            $data = array(
                "username" => $username,
                "email" => $email,
                "password" => $password,
                "confirmPass" => $confirm_password2,
                "status" => "Registered",
            );
            echo "Registered \n";

        }
    }
}
//...
//some other validations
//...

echo json_encode($data);
```

I have a feeling the way i am handling the json object is incorrect. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: echo "Registered \n"; remove this then check

Comment: What happens if you try to make an account with the username `x','x','x'); DROP TABLE users;--`?

Comment: `echo "Registered \n";` <- problem. If you were to actually look at the JSON output you would see that.

Comment: @castis haha you got me, im really just trying to wrap my head around json, jquery, etc... i'll fix the sql injection stuff after tho for sure.

Comment: thanks guys, removing the echo worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not

`echo`

anything other than `json_encode` when working with ajax `dataType : json` you have

`echo "Registered \n";`

before

`echo json_encode`

remove that and it should work

**EDIT:**

when you set the `dataType : "json"` in your `ajax` call then the response is expected to be in `json` when the call is finished, and any text other than `json` encoded string in response will result in an error. if you still need to debug and see what route the script is taking, you can add another index in `$data` ***(i assume that $data is an array)***, so it would be like

```
if($registered){
   $data['debug_logs'] .='Registration successfull----';
}

if($emailSent){
    $data['debug_logs'].='Email sent for registration-----';
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

and then in your ajax success function you can use it like

```
success:function(data){
console.log(data.debug_logs);
}
```

hope it clears your confusion.

Comment: thank seems to work. Thank you! but why can't i echo, i was putting the echo's in there for debugging purposed, i was tracking my code flow.

Comment: @Barcode I just updated my answer, see there for what you have asked

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `echo "Registered \n";` the line from your code when you `echo "Register";` the Ajax request return this back to the browser, and your actual data `echo json_encode($data);` never return back to the browser.

Comment: json_encode does return but along with the string registered  in start